# Delete row/section using NSFetchrequestController according to webservice response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using NSFetchrequestController to update tableview with core-data. When I delete row/section, temporally I made it to delete state and send it to web-service with a tag.

```
subtask.status = DELETED; //status = 4;
```

Full method is here.

```
MainTableViewCell *cell = (MainTableViewCell*)btn.superview.superview;
self.selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

Task *tobeUpdatedTask;
[popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

if (btn.titleLabel.tag == 8) { //Deleting Main Task/Section
    NSUInteger index = [self.sectionViewIndexMapping indexOfObject:btn.superview];
    if (index == NSNotFound){
        [self showAlert:@"Error Occured! Unable to find index of the section. Please go back to refresh data." WithTitle:ALERT];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.roundedButtonMenu removeFromSuperview];
        return;
    }
    if ([[self.krFetchedResultsController sections] count] <= index) {
        [self showAlert:@"Error Occured! Unable to find index of the section. Please go back to refresh data." WithTitle:ALERT];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.roundedButtonMenu removeFromSuperview];
        return;
    }
    id <KRFetchedResultsSectionInfo> si = [[self.krFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:index];

    Task *task = (Task *)si.theManagedObject;
    tobeUpdatedTask = task;
    if ([task.status isEqualToString:NEW]) {
        //[self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.managedObjectContext  deleteObject:si.theManagedObject];
    }else {
        task.status = DELETED;
        for (SubTask *st in task.subTasks) {
            st.status = DELETED;
        }
    }

}else { //Delete SubTask

    //FIXME: deleting countinously will kill the app. dismissing popover might work.
    if (self.selectedIndexPath == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to find index subtask object. Oops");
        return;
    }

    SubTask *subtask = [self.krFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath];
    tobeUpdatedTask = subtask.section;

    if ([subtask.status isEqualToString:NEW]) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.krFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath]];
    }else{
        subtask.status = DELETED;
        subtask.section.status = EDITED;
    }
}

//Remove rounded-menu if exists
[self.roundedButtonMenu removeFromSuperview];
[self.overlayView removeFromSuperview];

[self refreshDatesAndPercentage:tobeUpdatedTask];
[self save];
[self createGanttViewData:nil];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

According to web-service response I permanently remove it by fetching that object via particular subtask-id like the below code snipt.

```
NSArray *array = [self fetchObjectByEntityType:entityType byTaskID:[taskDic valueForKey:@"task_id"]]; // task_id from JSON dictionary
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
[self save];
```

However this works fine sometimes but most of the time application crashes with following error log in the console!

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (4) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (4), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'

I know this is due to not properly updating tableview rows/sections.But I've tried every possible way to make things correct.Please tell me what might I'm missing here or my approach! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you implementing the FRC delegate methods?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented them properly as in apple core-data recipes example. Do you want me to put them as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a fetched results controller then you should be its delegate and using the delegate methods to update the UI. If you're doing that, you should just be deleting the object from the store and allowing the FRC to do its work. You don't need to call `reloadData` yourself when you do the deletion.

Aside:

Using `btn.superview.superview` is not a reliable way to get the cell. It might work now but it won't work forever.

Comment: Hi Wain, Thank you for the answer. But I have two questions! First how I'm going to update UI using its delegate methods? Since the data Im getting is in JSON format and have to fetch that particular object and then delete it. And the reason I'm reloading tableview is when user clicks on row/section sometimes it's not returning valid section-row values. Secondly What  is the best way to get the cell? If you please give me some code sample it would be great help.

Comment: Th default implementations update the table view UI. If the section / row values are wrong then you should correct the logic. Add the index path the the button, maybe with `objc_setAssociatedObject`.

Comment: Thank you Wain, finally its working! No need to manually reload whole tableview, it makes tableview's indexes mess!